# how to expand a text area when click on

Tags: javascript, css

Im working on a small project which has a textarea and i need help in making the text area expand on mouse click  like that of twitter and facebook. the textarea should look like a textfield at first then when clicked on should expand.

Comment: Something like this jQuery example? http://jsfiddle.net/Hgvag/

Comment: all of the answers only expand the text area to a fixed length. The elastic plugin in pretty cool as it expands with every new line entered by the user

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Something like this would work...

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Y3rMM/

CSS...

```
.expand {
    height: 1em;
    width: 50%;
    padding: 3px;
}
```

HTML...

```
<textarea class="expand" rows="1" cols="10"></textarea>
```

jQuery...

```
$('textarea.expand').focus(function () {
    $(this).animate({ height: "4em" }, 500);
});
```

Comment: You can actually animate rows if you prefer: `$(this).animate({rows: 10}, 500);`

Answer (score 67):

This can be done without the use of JavaScript/jQuery, using CSS [transitions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_transitions).

```css
textarea {
    height: 1em;
    width: 50%;
    padding: 3px;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

textarea:focus {
    height: 4em;
}
```

```html
<textarea rows="1" cols="10"></textarea>
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. It's the simplest one and with the least dependencies.

Comment: I like this - but the problem for me is the textarea will return to height: 1em when not in focus.

Comment: Can we achieve this without pushing the elements underneath?

Answer (score 8):

This will work for you:

```
<textarea rows="1" cols="40" onfocus="this.rows=10;" style="resize: none;">Tweet Tweet....</textarea>
```

I used `onfocus` instead of `onclick` because `onclick` isn't fired if the user uses the tab key to move to the textarea. You'll also want to make sure the user can't resize it themselves - hence the style attribute.

You could also add `onblur="this.rows=1;"` to shrink it back down once the user moves out of your textarea.

Comment: Note this method doesn't require the overhead of any javascript libraries. But if you're using jQuery in other parts of the project then @wdm's code would be best.

Answer (score 2):

```
$("textarea").focus(function(){
    $("textarea").animate({ height: "70px" }, 500);
});
```

default css

```
textarea{ height: 50px;}
```

on focus textarea height will increase :) simple jquery

Answer (score 1):

use this plugin > http://plugins.jquery.com/project/elastic

very simple and effective !

Answer (score 1):

Based in [doog abides comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5648464/how-to-expand-a-text-area-when-click-on#comment-28588500) using jQuery, I enhanced the code to autoadjust approximately the number of rows acording to the length of the content, and return to 1 when focus is lost.

HTML:

```
<textarea class="expand" rows="1" cols="10"></textarea>
```

jQuery:

```
$('textarea.expand').focus(function () {
    $(this).animate({rows: Math.max(1,Math.ceil($(this).val().length/this.cols))}, 500);
});
$('textarea.expand').blur(function () {
    $(this).animate({rows: 1}, 500);
    //Resize back to one row if the textarea is manually resized via the handle
    $(this).css({height: ''});
    $(this).css({width: ''});
});
```

Comment: Something to note. This will not resize back to one row if the textarea is manually resized via the handle. When this action happens, height is applied via inline styling. A fix for this behavior is to clear the `style=' '` attribute as well. This can be done inline via `onblur='this.style=" ";'` or adding `$(this).css({ height: '' });` to the blur function above.

Comment: @illdapt I edited the answer for improve it as suggested, nice detail. Thanks for the comment!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with CSS only using `position: absolute`, which will make it float over other elements, and the `:focus` selector, which will be applied only when the element have the focus. First you need to reserve the textarea size enclosing it in an element:

```
<div class="textarea"><textarea></textarea></div>

div.textarea {
   height: 50px;
   width: 400px;
}
```

Then style the unfocused textarea

```
textarea {
   position: absolute;
   height: 50px;
   width: 400px;
   transition: all 200ms;
}
```

And finally the focused one

```
textarea:focus {
   z-index: 1001;
   min-height:250px;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7v60su9e/

Answer (score -1):

```
<textarea style="width:200px; height:50px;" id="ta"></textarea>

var ta = document.getElementById('ta');
ta.onclick = function(){
    this.style.height = "400px";
}
```

A quick fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/n6sgT/

Answer (score -1):

You can do something like below:

```
<textarea name="textBox" rows="1" cols="20" id="textBox" onfocus="document.getElementById('textBox').rows = 5;" >
```

Comment: Actually, the solution from Ben is ever simpler than mine.

Comment: jQuery does not have `$get`. It has `$.get` but that's something completely different. Besides that, why would you use a selector when you already have `this` in there?

Comment: Still quite ugly. `this.rows = 5;`